# Deploying VB.NET Windows Forms Application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need to create a winforms app that can be used by multiple users in different computers. Is it possible to have a client access the database from a server? And how do I deploy it? How can the client access the database from the server? Can I publish it as a clickonce application in visual studio?

Comment: Do some reading about data access in VB.NET. If you'd done that then you'd already know that you simply specify the database location in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Add your connection string to the server in app.config like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyConnString" connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

the use it like

```
Dim connectionString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnString").ConnectionString
```

check this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.110).aspx